# How to end a server socket listen

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

So what i'm trying to do is to make a multi-threaded server that creates threads for each client that connects to it, and replies back the string sent from the client.

It sort of works, but my server doesn't actually end properly. My KerboardInterrupt catch doesn't seem to work in windows command prompt, only thing that lets me exit the process would be ctrl + pause/break. Can anyone help me think of a way to get the server to end gracefully?

Server Code:

```
import socket
import threading
import time
import datetime
import sys

def getTime():
    ts = time.time()
    timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-      %d_%H:%M:%S')
    return timeStamp

def ThreadFunction(clientsocket, clientaddr):
    global ReceivedData
    global SentData
    while True:

        #Receive data from client
        data = clientsocket.recv(bufferSize)
        #Get client IP and port
        clientIP, clientSocket = clientsocket.getpeername()

        #Add to total amount of data transfered
        ReceiveDataSize = len(data)
        ReceivedData += ReceiveDataSize

        #LOg the received data
        text_file.write(str(getTime()) + "__ Size of data received (" +     clientIP + ":" + str(clientSocket) + ") = " + str(ReceiveDataSize) + '\n')

        #Send data
        clientsocket.send(data)
        SentDataSize = len(data)
        SentData += SentDataSize

        #Log the sent data
        text_file.write(str(getTime()) + "__ Size of data sent (" + clientIP + ":" + str(clientSocket) + ") = " + str(SentDataSize) + '\n')


def Close(counter, ReceivedData, SentData):
    print ("Shutting down Server...")
    serversocket.close()
    text_file.write("\n\nTotal # of connections: " + str(counter))
    text_file.write("\nTotal data received: " + str(ReceivedData))
    text_file.write("\nTotal data sent: " + str(SentData))
    text_file.close()
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    serverIP = raw_input('Enter your server IP \n')
    port = int(raw_input('What port would you like to use?\n'))

    # Maintain how many connections
    connections = []
    counter = 0

    # Maintain amount of data sent to and from server
    ReceivedData = 0
    SentData = 0
    bufferSize = 1024

    # Create and initialize the text file with the date in the filename in the logfiles directory
    text_file = open("MultiThreadedServerLog.txt", "w")
    address = (serverIP, port)
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Bind server to port
    serversocket.bind(address)

    # The listen backlog queue size
    serversocket.listen(50)
    print ("Server is listening for connections\n")

    try:
        while 1:
            # Accept client connections, increment number of connections
            clientsocket, clientaddr = serversocket.accept()
            counter += 1

            # Log client information
            print (str(clientaddr) + " : " + " Just Connected. \n Currently connected clients: " + str(counter) + "\n")
            text_file.write(str(getTime()) + " - " + str(clientaddr) + " : " + " Just Connected. \n Currently connected clients: " + str(counter) + "\n")
            clientThread = threading.Thread(target=ThreadFunction, args=(clientsocket, clientaddr))
            clientThread.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Keyboard interrupt occurred.")
        Close(counter, ReceivedData, SentData)
```

Client Code:

```
from socket import *
import threading
import time
import random
import sys
import datetime


serverIP = ""
port = 8005
message = ""
msgMultiple = 1


def getTime():
    ts = time.time()
    timeStamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
    return timeStamp



def run(clientNumber):
    buffer = 1024

    global totalTime

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((serverIP, port))
    threadRTT = 0

    while 1:
        for _ in range(msgMultiple):
            cData = message + "  From: Client " + str(clientNumber)

            # Start timer and send data
            start = time.time()
            s.send(cData.encode('utf-8'))
            print "Sent: " + cData

            # Stop timer when data is received
            sData = s.recv(buffer)
            end = time.time()

            # Keep track of RTT and update total time
            response_time = end - start
            threadRTT += end - start
            totalTime += response_time
            print "Received: " + cData + '\n'
            t = random.randint(0, 9)
            time.sleep(t)

        # Log information of Client
        text_file.write(
            "\nClient " + str(clientNumber) + " RTT time taken for " + str(msgMultiple) + " messages was: " + str(
                threadRTT) + " seconds.")
        threadRTT = 0
        break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    serverIP = raw_input('Enter the server IP: ')
    port = int(input('Enter the port: '))
    clients = int(input('Enter number of clients: '))
    message = raw_input('Enter a message to send: ')
    msgMultiple = int(input('Enter the number of times you would like to send the message: '))

    # Initialize Log file
    text_file = open("ClientLog.txt", "w")

    # Used to maintain list of all running threads
    threads = []
    totalTime = 0

    # Create a seperate thread for each client
    for x in range(clients):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run, args=[x])
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    # Calculations for log data
    bytes = sys.getsizeof(message)
    totalRequests = clients * msgMultiple
    totalBytes = totalRequests * bytes
    averageRTT = totalTime / totalRequests
    # Output data
    print("Bytes sent in message was : " + str(bytes))
    print("Total Data sent was : " + str(totalBytes) + " Bytes.")
    print("Average RTT was : " + str(averageRTT) + " seconds.")
    print("Requests was : " + str(totalRequests))

    # Write data to log file
    text_file.write("\n\n Bytes sent in message was : " + str(bytes))
    text_file.write("\nTotal Data sent was : " + str(totalBytes) + " Bytes.")
    text_file.write("\nAverage RTT was : " + str(averageRTT) + " seconds.")
    text_file.write("\nRequests was : " + str(totalRequests))
```

Also if anyone else has any general improvements they would add to this code, let me know. I'm still pretty new at python, and still rough at it.

Here is the normal intended input i'm getting from my server.

[image]

But when it gets to the last client that connects, it starts to drag on for some reason.

[image]

The last picture, the inputs go on for the majority of the text file, for a very long time. Seems like something isn't ending properly.

Comment: which `EOF` ? Socket, packet, file object ?

Comment: The `KeyboardInterrupt` will end the main thread only. You have to add a control mechanism to end the sub threads as well.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried making my threads a Daemon, but that didn't work. Any other way I can end the threads?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding an if statement that checks for a byte < 0 , if it is, end the socket.